# Вопрос по связи триггера и базы данных

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, триггер

Есть вот такая скромная бд:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
user_login VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
user_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
user_lastName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
user_password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(user_login));

CREATE TABLE errors (
error_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
error_input_date DATE NOT NULL,
error_short_descrip TEXT(512) NOT NULL,
error_full_descrip TEXT NOT NULL,
error_user VARCHAR(128) REFERENCES users(user_login),
error_status VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
error_urgency VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
error_criticality VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(error_id));

CREATE TABLE error_history (
history_user VARCHAR(128) REFERENCES users(user_login),
history_action VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
history_date DATE NOT NULL,
history_comment TEXT(512));
```

```sql
DELIMITER // 

CREATE TRIGGER add_error_history AFTER INSERT ON errors
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.error_status = "Новая") THEN
      INSERT INTO error_history VALUES(NEW.error_user, "Ввод", CURDATE());
    END IF;
  IF (NEW.error_status = "Открытая") THEN
      INSERT INTO error_history VALUES(NEW.error_user, "Открытие", CURDATE());
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

И когда я пытаюсь реализовать триггер, например:

```sql
INSERT INTO errors (error_input_date, error_short_descrip, error_full_descrip, error_user, error_status, error_urgency, error_criticality)
VALUES (CURDATE(),"WEDFGDD", "WEDFGDD", "WEDFGDD", "Новая", "WEDFGDD", "WEDFGDD");
```

То у меня появляется ошибка:

> ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Не могу понять, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Эта ошибка говорит о том что **количество столбцов не соответствует значению в строке 1** В `INSERT INTO` у вас 7 полей.А передаете в `VALUES` всего 6.

Comment: @Raharasomaha, не, я передаю 7 полей, первое- это текущая дата. Суть в том, что до прописания триггера все работало.

Comment: Проверьте внимательнее.У вас количество столбцов не соответствует значению в `VALUES`

Comment: @Raharasomaha, ты ошибаешься. Слушай, все хорошо уже работало, но эта странная проблема вышла после добавления триггера, вот чего я понять не могу.

Comment: *когда я пытаюсь реализовать триггер, например* Какие нафиг "например"? Точный текст создания триггера - включая оба переопределения DELIMITER, и точный текст сообщения об ошибке, включая количество пробелов и места переводов строк. Иначе и говорить не о чем... См. мою правку текста вопроса.

Comment: @Akina, окей, учту. А не знаете, почему такая ошибка выскакивает?

Comment: Ну я же сказал - хотите обсуждать ошибку, показывайте полный текст, приведший к ошибке, и полную цитату сообщения об ошибке. Сейчас я в упор не понимаю, какой текст вызвал ошибку. Один запрос без обрамления - мало.

Comment: @Akina, простите, но в дело в том что это все, я пытаюсь с помощью INSERT вставить в таблицу значения, которые привел в коде. Триггер видимо срабатывает на этот INSERT и выскакивает эта ошибка, никак не связанная на взгляд новичка с триггером. Потому что, когда я удаляю триггер и вставляю значения, все норм. Эта строка- единственное, что вылезает из сообщения об ошибке. А весь код, который я использовал до этого, тоже представлен.

Comment: Ну тогда посчитайте поля и значения в тексте ТРИГГЕРА. В запросе вставляется ТРИ значения в таблицу, имеющую ЧЕТЫРЕ поля.

Comment: @Akina, ахах, я думал, что не указывая NOT NULL, могу не вставлять значение в это поле. Спасибо.